# Autodesk Inventor Place Component with User Parameter Length

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I have some user parameters which I set in "fx":

[image]

Now I need to place standard square tube ("Place from Concent Center") with a length of `Tube0Length` mm. How can I do this? Inventor doesn't accept the parameter:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit with Content Center parts in Inventor, I managed to reproduce your problem and find kind of a workaround. It is not as smooth as just typing your parameter name in the Content Center window, but maybe it helps you.

1. Place the part that you need with an arbitrary length in your assembly.
2. Rightclick and open the part (don't click change size but actually open it)
3. Use Save As to save it as an own part, otherwise you can't modify the parameters.
4. In the saved file, add your parameter and use it as new extrusion length.
5. Replace the initial arbitrary length part with your saved individual part.

This is of course a bit clumsy, but it gets as close to your problem as I can come up with right now.